# 1/f noise generation

Tags: discrete-signals, audio, frequency-spectrum, noise, sound

Recently I was reading a paper about the pink noise generation. But I don't have any background of this field.

I am confused with some part in the paper.

First, the Voss's algorithm generated a sequence of numbers, how do they use this sequence of number generated figure 1.

[image]

Second,in section 5.2, how do they get the melody shown in figure 11, figure 12 and figure 13?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Here is link of the paper: Generating 1/f Noise Sequences as Constraint Satisfaction: The Voss Constraint.](http://ijcai.org/papers15/Papers/IJCAI15-352.pdf)

Comment: They seem to be using their own constraint solving software.